# Keras Architecture is not the same for the saved and loaded model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am currently looking into CycleGAN and im using [simontomaskarlssons](https://github.com/simontomaskarlsson/CycleGAN-Keras) github repository as my baseline. My problem arises when the training is done and I want to use the saved model to generate new samples. Here the model architecture for the loaded model are different from the initialized generator. The direct link for the saveModel function is [here](https://github.com/simontomaskarlsson/CycleGAN-Keras/blob/master/model.py#L760).

When I initialize the generator that does the translation from domain A to B the summary looks like the following ([line in github](https://github.com/simontomaskarlsson/CycleGAN-Keras/blob/master/model.py#L175)). This is as expected since my input image is (140,140,1) and I am expecting an output image as (140,140,1):

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)            (None, 140, 140, 1)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reflection_padding2d_1 (Reflect (None, 146, 146, 1)  0           input_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 140, 140, 32) 1600        reflection_padding2d_1[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
instance_normalization_5 (Insta (None, 140, 140, 32) 64          conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

...

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_12 (Activation)      (None, 140, 140, 32) 0           instance_normalization_23[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reflection_padding2d_16 (Reflec (None, 146, 146, 32) 0           activation_12[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_26 (Conv2D)              (None, 140, 140, 1)  1569        reflection_padding2d_16[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_13 (Activation)      (None, 140, 140, 1)  0           conv2d_26[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 2,258,177
Trainable params: 2,258,177
Non-trainable params: 0
```

When the training is done I want to load the saved models to generate new samples (translation from domain A to domain B). In this case it does not matter if the model is successful at translating the images or not. I load the model with the following code:

```
# load json and create model
json_file = open('G_A2B_model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()

loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json, custom_objects={'ReflectionPadding2D': ReflectionPadding2D, 'InstanceNormalization': InstanceNormalization})
```

or the following which gives the same result.

```
loaded_model = load_model('G_A2B_model.h5', custom_objects={'ReflectionPadding2D': ReflectionPadding2D, 'InstanceNormalization': InstanceNormalization})
```

Where ReflectionPadding2D is initialized as (note that I have a separate file for loading the model then for training CycleGAN):

```
# reflection padding taken from
# https://github.com/fastai/courses/blob/master/deeplearning2/neural-style.ipynb
class ReflectionPadding2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, padding=(1, 1), **kwargs):
        self.padding = tuple(padding)
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim=4)]
        super(ReflectionPadding2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def compute_output_shape(self, s):
        return (s[0], s[1] + 2 * self.padding[0], s[2] + 2 * self.padding[1], s[3])

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        w_pad, h_pad = self.padding
        return tf.pad(x, [[0, 0], [h_pad, h_pad], [w_pad, w_pad], [0, 0]], 'REFLECT')
```

Now that my model is loaded I want to translate images from domain A to domain B. Here I expected the output shape to be (140,140,1) but surprisingly it is (132,132,1). I checked the architecture summary for G_A2B_model that clearly shows that the output is of shape (132,132,1):

```
Model: "G_A2B_model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)            (None, 140, 140, 1)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reflection_padding2d_1 (Reflect (None, 142, 142, 1)  0           input_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 136, 136, 32) 1600        reflection_padding2d_1[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
instance_normalization_5 (Insta (None, 136, 136, 32) 64          conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

...

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
instance_normalization_23 (Inst (None, 136, 136, 32) 64          conv2d_transpose_2[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_12 (Activation)      (None, 136, 136, 32) 0           instance_normalization_23[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reflection_padding2d_16 (Reflec (None, 138, 138, 32) 0           activation_12[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_26 (Conv2D)              (None, 132, 132, 1)  1569        reflection_padding2d_16[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_13 (Activation)      (None, 132, 132, 1)  0           conv2d_26[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 2,258,177
Trainable params: 2,258,177
Non-trainable params: 0
```

What I don't understand is why the output shape is (132x132x1). But I can see that hte problem arises in  the reflectionPadding2D where the output shape of the initialized generator is (146,146,1) and the output shape of save generator is (142,142,1). But I have no idea why this is happening? Because they should in theory be the same size.

Comment: Your default value for padding is `(1, 1)`. Have you checked if you are using a different parameter when calling the constructor for `ReflectionPadding2D`? I think it should be `(3, 3)`.

Comment: @RicardoAbe that must the reason why it does not work. But as you can see [here](https://github.com/simontomaskarlsson/CycleGAN-Keras/blob/master/model.py#L330) it uses (3,3) but in Rk function it uses (1,1). It seems like it uses the constructors value for padding (1,1)? Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you persist your architecture using `model.to_json`, the method `get_config` is called so that the layer attributes are saved as well. As you are using a custom class without that method, the default value for padding is being used when you call `model_from_json`.

Using the following code for `ReflectionPadding2D` should solve your problem, just run the training step again and reload the model.

```py
class ReflectionPadding2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, padding=(1,1), **kwargs):
        self.padding = tuple(padding)
        super(ReflectionPadding2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def compute_output_shape(self, s):
        return (s[0], s[1] + 2 * self.padding[0], s[2] + 2 * self.padding[1], s[3])

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        w_pad, h_pad = self.padding
        return tf.pad(x, [[0, 0], [h_pad, h_pad], [w_pad, w_pad], [0, 0]], 'REFLECT')

    # This is the relevant method that should be added
    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'padding': self.padding

        }
        base_config = super(ReflectionPadding2D, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Comment: I added this in my loading script, but it did not change anything. Still the same output from: reflection_padding2d_1 (Reflect (None, 142, 142, 1). And the output shape is still (132,132,1). Hmm... Do you know what can be wrong?

Comment: Check your json file and search for all `ReflectionPadding2D` entries, there must be two of them with key `config.padding` = `[3, 3]`. If that is true, then the problem must be at your load model (btw, I had to add a parameter to it: `model_from_json(fh.read(), custom_objects={'ReflectionPadding2D': ReflectionPadding2D})`, where `fh` is a handler for the json file).

Comment: I checked the json file and none of the ReflectionPadding2D has a key config.padding. I uploaded the file [here](https://gofile.io/?c=W4i3BB) . Can you see what is wrong?

Comment: Have you run the training with the updated version of `ReflectionPadding2D`? Analyzing the json, it looks like it was generated based on the old layer without the `get_config` method.

Comment: Ah no I didnt trained again. Your right. Ill Try that and return :)

Comment: My bad, I should have explained it better. I have edited the answer.

Comment: This worked! Great. Thanks for taking your time to answer :)